# how to get iterate object which is inside the array that array also inside the another array in angular

Tags: angular

```
this.weekDates.forEach((wdate) => {
  this.billingservice.getbill(this.formatDate(wdate)).subscribe(info => {
    this.objArray.push(info)
    // console.log(info)
  })
  // console.log((wdate));
})
this.objArray.forEach((outer, index) => {
  console.log(outer, "outerloop-", index);
  outer.forEach(inner => {
    // this.sumPrice = inner.grandTotol
    this.sumPrice = this.sumPrice + (inner.grandTotol)
    console.log(inner.grandTotal, "innerloop")
  });
});
```

How to determine  sumPrice value here in my case it shows me undefined

Comment: what does `console.log(outer,"outerloop-",index);` print? And what would `inner` look like, inside `outer.forEach`?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to calculate the result of something that has not even been evaluated yet.

The `objArray` will get populated asynchronously and that too after the `this.objArray.forEach((outer, index) => { ... })` function has executed.

What you are supposed to do instead is to calculate the sum only once the whole `objArray` is populated. In order to do that, you could use **[`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin)** and wait for all the `this.billingservice.getbill(this.formatDate(wdate))` calls to happen. Once that's done you could just calculate the total from the returned array.

Something like this:

```
forkJoin(
  ...this.weekDates.map(wdate =>
    this.billingService.getBill(this.formatDate(wdate))
  )
).subscribe((res: any[]) => {
  this.sumPrice = res.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.grandTotal, 0);
});
```

> Here's a **[Working Code Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-get-sum-of-items-retrieved-asynchronously?file=src/app/app.component.ts)** for your reference.